# Angular routing catch back button and prompt user, with no routing history

Tags: javascript, html, angular, web-applications, modular

I have two angular apps, one acts like a hub app (that launches (links to) other angular apps), while another acts as more of an editor (like) component host (but is a septate app). (*as far as why, micro-services, modular deployment, yada yada*). The issue I am running into is the app launches directly into editor screen, I want to confirm that the user wants to leave that screen, but because the user is immediately taken to this editor screen, and because it's a new instance of a angular app, there is no app routing history, so I believe my `canDeactive` method is skipped al together. Is there any way to work around this or suggestions, etc?

one idea I've consider is first loading to a temp component, that then redirects to the editor component, but then I think that would have the side effect of when the user does go back, it would just redirect them back to the open editor, etc, and not back to the hub app.

[image]

Comment: You are building an App that must open an App, and you have them separated ? It does not make sense for me to design such an App. I would use multiple router outlet and deal with route params https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-multiple-outlets/

Comment: This couples the two apps, I could not independently update one without updating the other. Think microservices. Trying to decouple things.